# Should I quit my Senior Software Engineer job and search for another company?

Tags: professionalism, unprofessional-behavior

I think I am reaching some kind of boiling point, so I appreciate every single comment, thought or feeling around this. Please accept my most sincere apologies if there is any mistake or rule not followed in my text, but is my first post here. I've been thinking for months about posting this, and almost one can say I am looking for help, not advice.

Let's crack in:

I work as a Senior Software Dev in a big company at New York, USA, in case it helps with the context.

Here I go:

A year ago, some big fish in my company said (while probably holding  the seventh cocktail on his hand):

---

> Hey, what if we split our 20-years-old project in 10000 parts so we
>   can have 10000 small teams working independently in each part?

---

I was then "kindly forced" to get into the project.

This project is formed by me and 4 other guys, let me ellaborate and present you **the 4 guys that would have Stephen King himself crying in fear in a corner!**:

- **Shadow guy**: That kind of guy that is always speaking like as if he is some kind of Jon Skeet but actually does nothing. Nobody ever knows what is he spending time in. Contribution to the project: 0%.
- **Annoying guy**: He loves meetings, probably to enmascarate the fact that he is not good at his job, so he can fill the time with meetings. He's always asking for tech help. Loves to bring stupid questions up to keep us talking a little bit more.
- **Boss-alike-dev guy**: He acts (large story) as the manager, but he is not the manager. (The project lacks of it.) He's well known along the company thanks to his bad character, which is almost impossible to stand.  Do you guys know that "don't treat your devs like mushrooms" (without info in a dark place) principle. He loves it. He's good at a technical level, but a person you definitely don't want to work with every day. (Or even a day in the year).

  -**Dev "in-love-with-boss-alike-dev-guy" guy**: I know this has another name, but it implies the noun "sucker" along a part of the masculine body, so I won't say it here. Always religiously supports "Boss-alike-dev guy", even though he is saying that 1+1 = 30491093.

  Once that has been said, I've got the feeling that "Boss-alike-dev guy" and me are the only ones working hard on the project.

  It's been a while since I've been doing awful tasks, that kind of tasks no one wants to do in the project, but I didn't say anything and just worked hard as long as I love my job and the technology I use.

  Last week, we have been told that we're not reaching our objectives, and that we possibly ain't having the objectives bonus, which is like a 15% of my year salary.

  On the top of that, I've been told to switch to other set of awful tasks, but this time with a technology I hate.

  **My question is:**

  *Shall I quit my job and search for new horizons?*

**Thank you**, I mean it, for any advice.

**EDIT**: I forgot to add something as important as my role within this "team". I am the expert on an specific technology, people tell me I am very good at my job and my colleagues outside this "team" see me as a reference.

**EDIT 2**: Just in case someone is wondering (legitimatelly), I have been working in 6-7 companies and no one ever complained about me. Actually people says that they love my "comrade spirit" and my funny attitude while being as professional as I can. I don't like to say good things about myself, but experience tells me that I am a nice person to work with.

Comment: I say this is a rant because there is a lot superfluous information that does not help the reader at all in giving you advice. It would suffice to say that you dislike or don't get along with your co-workers, badmouthing each of them on a personal level does not exactly exude professionalism, and if I were considering you for a position and found out that you wrote this question I would seriously think twice. I think this is more important advice than whether or not to look for a different job.

Comment: For who you need to report? Your boss/manager/whatever needs to know that the other guys not work as expected and the "Boss-alike-dev guy" is a terrible person to work with.

Comment: I think that every bit of information adds something to the context, that's why I added it. "dislike" or "don't get along with co-workers" lacks of many hues. I don't find any personal reference on them, I am just stating contrasted facts. Independently of it, if I were considering to work for a position of your company (or department) or whatever it is, and found out that you wrote this comment, I won't think twice; I will just decline it. You don't know me at all buddy, so don't act like as if you do.

Comment: @Dherik I am supposed to report to my manager, who is "Boss-alike-dev guy" manager too, and, (look, what a coincidence!) is his wife as well :-)

Comment: Youre right, I don't know you, and neither will any other potential hiring manager. I'm just saying that calling your co-worker a cocksucker on a professional Q&A forum reflects poorly on you. You can take that advice or leave it, it matters none to me.

Comment: I didn't call him that explicitly, I am just saying that he is an adulator. I appreciate your advice. I just wanted to express what he is with a bit of sense of humour with more or less success.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need to go look for another job.

It's apparent that your team isn't a team, it's just the dregs of your company and it's unclear why you've been included in this team or even what your role is within it.

So look for another job for a company that has clear leadership and management, and hopefully has people that you can respect.

Comment: "it's just the dregs of your company". Boom. Just like that. You nailed it, couldn't say it better. I edited my question with my role, in case it helps. Thank you so much for your concise, but truly helpful answer.

Comment: **Always** keep an eye on other jobs.